Unity is not finding an object on scene, other scripts do just fine



using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public HPManager hpManager;
    [SerializeField] public GameObject redBar;
    [SerializeField] public Slider yellowBar;
    [SerializeField] private float lerpSpeed = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxHp;
    [SerializeField] private float minHp = 0;
    [SerializeField] private int health;


    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Awake()
    {
        
    }
    void Start()
    { 
        hpManager = GameObject.Find("HurtAndHitBoxSystem").GetComponent<HPManager>();
        hpManager = GameObject.Find("HurtAndHitBoxSystem").GetComponent<HPManager>();

        //hpManager = transform.Find("HurtAndHitBoxSystem").GetComponent<HPManager>();
        redBar = GameObject.Find("RedBar");
        yellowBar = GameObject.Find("YellowBar").GetComponent<Slider>();


        maxHp = hpManager.GetPlayerHP();
       // health = (float)maxHp;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

not the slider component, not the bar Gameobject, not the hpManager script, nothing.  nothing gets instantiated by other scripts, they are there on the scene before i press play, it is just refusing to do anything it is told to.
got other classes that work fine.
i placed this class on a cube on scene and nothing even if it is on top of the hierarchy.
this has dumbfound me.  Any clues?
in the inspector, it can find the objects with the required components , but it just doesnt do it after i press play.  it is not the first script that's written this way  and every other one works.
tried placing  the code in update but nothing, it's as it cannot find them,
there's a canvas on the scene but  the HPManager is on scene on a gameobject on top of the hierarchy.
yes, everything is active, already on scene before pressing play.
addendum: HPManager doesnt have a tick like every other component(it physically doesnt, i cant tick it) i comment every line pertaining to it , and it magically finds every other  object .

I assume you did not reference your objects trough the Unity inspector. You simply need to attach your script to some object in your scene and then, drag and drop your desired objects from the scene into the script's public fields trough the inspector.

It is not clear what the issue could be so I will suggest a few things to try and figure out what the issue is, along with some solutions.

First, you can try and assign the components through HealthBar gameobject inspector since you marked them as [SerializeField], but if you choose this way you should delete the GameObject.Find() lines because in case your script can't find the objects it will assign them as null.
Second, make sure that the names of your GameObjects that you are trying to find are all correct and also make sure they have the correct components that you want.

You can read more directly from Unity's manual regarding the GameObject.Find() method
Lastly, @derHugo is an expert on Unity, so you can reach out for farther support.

Ok this is interesting, i Renamed the object to just HitAndHurt, and it finds it like that.  which is weird as i only copied and pasted the object's name to avoid confusion.
just gonna leave that there for anyone that has the same issue.
